# Remove padding on TextEditor

Tags: swift, swiftui

My custom text editor below once you click on the pen to edit, a new space appears so the text from before is not on the same line as the new one. How can I fix this? Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State var name: String = "test"
    @State var showEdit: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                if(showEdit) {
                    CustomTextEditor.init(placeholder: "My unique name", text: $name)
                        .font(.headline)
                } else {
                    Text(name)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                showEdit.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextEditor: View {
    let placeholder: String
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if text.isEmpty  {
                Text(placeholder)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary.opacity(0.25))
            }
            TextEditor(text: $text)
        }.onAppear() {
            UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        }.onDisappear() {
            UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to have the same padding properies as inserting a simple `Text("")` so when I switch between `Text("xyz")` and `TextEditor(text: $xyz)` it has the same padding alignment. Right now TextEditor has a weird padding.

Comment: Add this to your Text: `.padding(.horizontal,5)` while leaving TextEditor's padding untouched, you will get what you expected, almost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will drive yourself insane trying to line up a `Text` and a `TextEditor` (or a `TextField`, for that matter), so don't try. Use another, disabled, `TextEditor` instead, and control the `.opacity()` on the top one depending upon whether the bound variable is empty or not. Like this:

```
struct CustomTextEditor: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @State private var placeholder: String

    init(placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
        _placeholder = State(initialValue: placeholder)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextEditor(text: $placeholder)
                .disabled(true)
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .opacity(text == "" ? 0.7 : 1)
        }
    }
}
```

This view will show the placeholder if there is no text, and hide the placeholder as soon as there is text.

Edit:

You don't need the button, etc. in your other view. It becomes simply:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextEditor.init(placeholder: "My unique name", text: $name)
            .font(.headline)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

and if you need a "Done" button on the keyboard, change your `CustomTextEditor()` to this:

```
struct CustomTextEditor: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @State private var placeholder: String

    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    
    init(placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
        _placeholder = State(initialValue: placeholder)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextEditor(text: $placeholder)
                .disabled(true)
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .opacity(text == "" ? 0.7 : 1)
                .focused($isFocused)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button {
                    isFocused = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Done")
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .padding(.trailing)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it has a weird behavior where the initial text (before clicking the button) is all the wayyyy up

Comment: You don't need the button. This works off of simply whether you have entered text or not. I updated the code with more examples.

Comment: This is brilliant thank you