# Remove padding of TextEditor

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently doing a sort of an edition view and as `TextEditor` doesn't have a place holder, I am faking one by putting an overlay with a `Text("Description")` when the `TextEditor` is empty.

The problem is as you can see in the screen, `TextEditor` adds a small padding and I would like to know if you can remove it

[image: TextEditor padding]

```swift
TextEditor(text: $description)
  .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
    if description.isEmpty {
      Text("Description")
      .foregroundStyle(.tertiary)
      .allowsHitTesting(false)
    }
}
```

The white bar is where the `TextEditor` lets us type.

And the post [Remove padding on TextEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259342/remove-padding-on-texteditor) didn't help me at all.

**EDIT:** For now, I have used a simple `.offset(x: -5)` but as it's a really good solution, I'll leave this open if someone has a better solution :)

Comment: Is easier if you put another disabled `TextEditor` in the overlay with the desired text.

Comment: I mean I could yeah @GuillermoJiménez but if I do this, then it won't be aligned with my other texts in the view

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue so I have make my own text editor with palceholder. Please have a loot at this simple code. You just need to Initialised it with binding variables for use.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MLBTextEditor: View {
    
    var title: String
    var text: Binding<String>
    var placeHolder: String
    
    @FocusState private var detailIsFocused: Bool
    
    init(title: String, text: Binding<String>, placeholder: String) {
           UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.placeHolder = placeholder
        
       }

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 7) {
            if !title.isEmpty {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.custom(Nunito.Medium.rawValue, size: 13))
            }
            
            
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                
                if text.wrappedValue.isEmpty {
                    Text(placeHolder)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.custom(Roboto.Regular.rawValue, size: 14))
                }
                
                TextEditor(text: text)
                    .font(.custom(Roboto.Regular.rawValue, size: 14))
                    .padding(15)
                    .focused($detailIsFocused)
                    .opacity(text.wrappedValue.isEmpty ? 0.25 : 1)
                    .foregroundColor(self.text.wrappedValue == placeHolder ? .gray : .primary)
                // this onchange method is use to close the keyboard
                    .onChange(of: text.wrappedValue) { _ in
                        if !text.wrappedValue.filter({ $0.isNewline }).isEmpty {
                            detailIsFocused = false
                        }
                    }
                
                
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                if text.wrappedValue.isEmpty {
                    text.wrappedValue = " "
                }
            }

            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct MLBTextEditor_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MLBTextEditor(title: "", text: .constant(""), placeholder: "Name please")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working... If you look here https://ibb.co/BrZZw66 , the start of the TextEditor still have a padding and I don't want to add padding everywhere in my app just to fit with it. I would like to REMOVE the padding of the TextEditor

Comment: it only taking padding a leading side. You can remove it with .offset(x: -5)